# What happens between the point corresponding to ultimate tensile strength and fracture point?

Tags: stress-strain

[image]
A rod is subjected to tensile stress and it is plotted against the strain developed. This graphs can be found in any standard material science and mechanical engineering text books.
 If the load is removed gradually at point C, then the rod will follow the path CC' and will have a permanent set OC'(if I'm not wrong).

1. Will the rod follow a parallel path parallel to CC' when released
   from a point between D and E?
2. What will happen if the stress is increased beyond UTS instead of
   decreasing it as shown in graph? Will the rod break immediately?
3. Will the part DE be stable? I mean if we leave the rod at some
       point between D and E, will it remain at the same point without
       further elongation?

Comment: This question has few sub-questions all aimed to understand what is happening between points D and E. For some, this question might seem broad, but I've tried my best to keep it focused. I feel all these questions are interconnected, hence am posting them consciously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of engineering stress strain curves are actually force x displacement curves. The mobile part of the machine moves at constant speed, and a strain gage attached to the sample records the displacement of a given length. At the same time a load cell detects the force and the results are being plotted. Force is an output of the displacement.

If we input the initial area of the test sample, the result can be displayed: $\sigma \times \epsilon$.

So, if at any time, the movement is stopped and reversed, the load cell will record a decrease of force proportional to the displacement. That is, a straight line parallel to OA. That is Hooke's law.

When the max. force is reached, further deformation will be non uniform along the test specimen. A "neck" starts to form in some region, and the load cell records a decrease of force. That is because the area of the neck decreases, and additionally there is a stress concentration at that region. As the necking progresses, the force associated to a given displacement falls.

But if the machine stops moving, the position of the graph is maintained. Unless the temperature is high enough to thermally ativated stress relieve metallurgical processes begins.

Comment: I've updated the diagram with the line FF and FF'''. If the machine pulling the rod is stopped at point F and the rod is left on its own, will return to point F' or F'' or any other point?

Comment: If the machine is simply stopped, the force keeps the same, the graph doesn't move from point F. But when the force is released it goes to F'. It is commom to interrupt the tensile test that way, to avoid the vibration of the fracture.